# UITapGestureRecognizer does not work with UIView animate

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to call an action when I tap on a UIImage at the time of its animation.
I've seen similar questions, but I could not apply these solutions to my case.
Please help.

xcode 9.2
swift 4

```
import UIKit

class MyCalssViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // action by tap
        let gestureSwift2AndHigher = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.actionUITapGestureRecognizer))
        myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureSwift2AndHigher)

    }

    // action by tap
    @objc func actionUITapGestureRecognizer (){

        print("actionUITapGestureRecognizer - works!") // !!! THIS DOES NOT WORK !!!

    }

    // hide UIImage before appear
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        myImageView.center.y += view.bounds.height

    }

    // show UIImage after appear with animation
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, animations: {
            self.myImageView.center.y -= self.view.bounds.height
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818440/update-views-frame-while-its-being-animated/37819789#37819789

Comment: "I've seen similar questions, but I could not apply these solutions"  What are those solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in the option `.allowUserInteraction` like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You just missed a line, enabling user interaction on the view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // action by tap
    let gestureSwift2AndHigher = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.actionUITapGestureRecognizer))
    myImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureSwift2AndHigher)

}
```

Comment: thnx, but this line do not help

Answer (score 0):

```
  let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.clickedImageView(_:)))
  myImageview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
  myImageview.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

// MARK: - Gesture Recognizer action

    func clickedImageView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
       // Write your action here.
    }
```

Comment: this part " _ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer " nothing to changed

Comment: sender will pass the particular UITapGestureRecognizer for validation purpose

Comment: i understand, but action by tap still don't work when ImageView animate

Comment: Can you share animation function

Comment: Please, look higher, i already do it in my question

"
// hide UIImage before appear
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        myImageView.center.y += view.bounds.height

    }

    // show UIImage after appear with animation
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, animations: {
            self.myImageView.center.y -= self.view.bounds.height
        })
    }
"

Comment: I think your View was uppending above imageview. for testing purpose hide the view and check once.

Comment: sorry, but I'm not sure, that understand you

Comment: Ya bro, I understood. I have a doubt while animation that view is coming above view. Check the Stack of the Imageview & View position